# How can I replace a list of strings in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to replace a list `["ABC","DEF"]` with a single list item `["XYZ"]` as follows, but can't figure out if the comma (,) needs to be escaped or there is something else required in this syntax:

```yaml
- name: replace list of strings
  replace:
          path: /tmp/file1
          backup: yes
          regexp: "ABC\",\"DEF"
          replace: "XYZ"
```

When I run this task, it does not do the replacement as expected.

Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this in ansible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put regex into the [single-quoted](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) string. In this case, you don't have to escape double-quotes, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: replace list of strings
      replace:
        path: /tmp/file1
        backup: yes
        regexp: '"ABC","DEF"'
        replace: '"XYZ"'
```

Given the file

```sh
shell> cat /tmp/file1
["ABC","DEF"]
```

The list will be replaced

```sh
shell> cat /tmp/file1
["XYZ"]
```